# Why is URLDownloadToFile() not downloading my file?

Tags: c++, winapi

So I am trying to create a function to download a file with a variable address depending on the user with a string input using `URLDownloadToFile()` however it does not seem to actually download the file to the disk. It skips `S_OK`, `E_OUTOFMEMORY` and `INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE` to `UNKNOWN_ERROR`. Using `GetLastError()` returns `2`, checking up online said that meant `"Not Found"`. I'm not sure whether this was the website I was using or not (it's my own server with Node.JS using `res.download(path, filename)`). Hope for help, the code is below.

Just a note, everything is properly included as needed and the process (safely) runs with `SE_DEBUG_NAME` so it hopefully should not be a permission error.

```
// Convert String To Wide String
wstring S2WS(const string& str) {
    int length;
    int slength = (int)str.length() + 1;
    length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[length];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), slength, buffer, length);
    wstring out(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;
    return out;
}

// Download File
int download(string url) {
    wstring wUrl = S2WS(url);
    LPCWSTR lUrl = wUrl.c_str();
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
    HRESULT response = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, lUrl, path, 0, NULL);
    if (response == S_OK) {
        cout << "S_OK" << endl;
    } else if (response == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
        cout << "E_OUTOFMEMORY" << endl;
    } else if (response == INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE) {
        cout << "INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "UNKNOWN_ERROR" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Example Usage
int main() {
    download("http://somewebsite.com/files/textfile.txt");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the path argument to URLDownloadToFile does not require the actual file name? As far as I can tell you are only passing a directory name.

Comment: @Wander3r had answered this, I had added it to the code, `GetLastError()` no longer outputs anything anymore, still `UNKNOWN_ERROR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [URLDownloadToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v%3Dvs.85)), the `path` should be file path not a directory path. You could append some file name to the `path` variable and it should work.

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
wcscat_s(path, L"\\filename.txt");
```

Comment: Added this into the code to make sure. It still runs down to `UNKNOWN_ERROR`, only this time there is no output from `GetLastError()`, previously it was outputting 2.

Comment: I tried your code with my changes and able to save the file successfully from `int main() {
 download("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/file-sample_100kB.rtf");
}`

Comment: Ok. I checked again with a written link rather than a referenced link. It seems to work now. It just means something was wrong with how I checked for the link at an index of a string. I will need to recheck it is all. This solved it. Thanks.