# Downloading a file using URLDownloadToFile

Tags: c++

i tried using URLDownloadToFile

**the actual code i used**

```
URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/file-sample_100kB.rtf", L"google.com.file", 0, NULL);
```

I never got an error but the file never downloaded

I've tried a different directory before i used `google.com.file`

I also saw somewhere that you need to point to a file inside of a directory, this also did not work
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687422/why-is-urldownloadtofile-not-downloading-my-file) to that post

Comment: Where is URLDownloadToFile defined?

Comment: i dont have it defined anywhere, just `#include<tchar.h>` and  `#include<urlmon.h>`

Comment: @MeatMan It seems that your URL is working, because I have just downloaded that RTF file. But I think that the `path` parameter should refer to a file path in your system (e.g. `C:\\Temp\\DownloadedFile.txt`) instead of that `L"google.com.file"` you are using. Maybe you have a file called `L"google.com.file"` in the folder from where you are running your app.

Comment: @ScottHunter It's an old [Microsoft Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v%3Dvs.85)) API call.

Comment: @MeatMan It would be good if you added some error checking to your `URLDownloadToFile` call. Grab the `HRESULT` to an `hr` and check it with `SUCEEDED(hr)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

i found the issue @rturrado made me realize that it downloads the file from the url to that file and keeps the same extension, sorry wasting your time

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped!